# POST two InputStreams in a javax Request

Tags: java, rest, resteasy

I'm trying to send a request to an endpoint that takes a form with two files. The method I'm currently trying fails on the last line:

```
WebTarget client = myUtils.createClient(URL, ENDPOINT);

MultivaluedMap<String, InputStream> formData = new MultivaluedHashMap<>();
formData.add(FILE_1, stream1);
formData.add(FILE_2, stream2);

Entity<MultivaluedMap<String, InputStream>> entity = Entity.entity(formData, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE);

Response response = client.request().post(entity);
```

The error reached is

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003215: could not find writer for content-type multipart/form-data type: javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedHashMap
```

Changing `MediaType` to `APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE` yields

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.io.SequenceInputStream cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Is there a better way to handle POSTing a form with two files?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways. 
If you are using Jersey, One way is to do something like:

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataMultiPart;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.file.FileDataBodyPart;
....
....
   FileDataBodyPart fileDataBodyPart = 
             new FileDataBodyPart("file", new File("/filelocation/file.txt"));
    FormDataMultiPart formDataMultiPart = (FormDataMultiPart) 
                        FormDataMultiPart.field("somekey","somevalue")
                             .bodyPart( fileDataBodyPart);

     WebTarget target = client.target(restServiceURLYouwant);
     Response response = target.request().post(Entity.entity(formDataMultiPart, 
      formDataMultiPart.getMediaType()));

       formDataMultiPart.close();
```

Another way is to use Apache HttpUtils

```
 import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
 import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
 ....
 ....
 MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity();
 FileBody fb = new FileBody(file, "application/octet-stream");
 multipartEntity.addPart(fb);

 HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient() ;
 HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost (url) ; 
    //url above should be url of the Rest service endpoint
 httpPostRequest.setEntity(multiPartEntity) ;
               
 HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPostRequest) ;
```